# Is MonoGame really cross-platform?

Tags: mono, xna

When I download MonoGame (which I will use in place of XNA since I'm on a Mac) and unzip it, all the MonoDevelop solution files are named `MonoGame.Framework.[PLATFORM NAME].sln`, with `[PLATFORM NAME]` being, well, the name of the OS. And the code in [the tutorials](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials) is different for each platform, so it appears that for a MonoGame app to run on a different machine, it must be ported. Is this correct? If so, what other versions of XNA are there for Mono, preferably that work on the Xbox 360? I've seen MonoXNA, but it doesn't seem mature enough to use as of this post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MonoGame makes *your code* cross-platform by providing the XNA API on multiple platforms. (But it does not make your compiled *binary* cross-platform like, say, Flash or Java would.)

MonoGame *itself* is not cross-platform, in the sense that there is a version of it for each platform - as each version contains a large amount of platform-specific code required to implement the XNA API for that platform.

(Although in reality substantial amount of MonoGame code *is* cross-platform and shared between different MonoGame versions - because it is, in turn, built on layers like Mono, OpenGL and OpenAL that, like MonoGame, provide a consistent API with a different underlying implementation on platform.)

This is exactly the same as Microsoft's official XNA implementation. There are 3 different versions of the XNA library (Windows, Xbox 360, and Windows Phone). They all provide the XNA API. And your code that uses the XNA API can be built for any of those platforms.

---

MonoXNA is pretty out of date, and most of its useful code has made it into MonoGame anyway.

As far as I know there are no other current XNA implementations that use Mono to run on OSX. There's [ExEn](http://andrewrussell.net/exen/), which uses Mono - but only for iOS and Android.

Your only option for using XNA on Xbox 360 is to use Microsoft's version. But this doesn't preclude you from also compiling your code against MonoGame.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the reply. Is there any way to somehow use _Microsoft_ XNA with MonoDevelop, e.g. linking some assemblies to the C# compiler? I'd still love to use the framework, just preferably on a Mac. :)

Comment: @Jwosty Do you mean: Compile Windows/Xbox 360/Windows Phone XNA games using MonoDevelop on a Mac? I think that this is *technically* possible. C# is like Java in the sense that the binaries *are* actually cross platform - so it would just be a matter of setting the appropriate platform-specific references for each platform build. But it is a bad idea because you won't be able to run them (testing and debugging). *And* you won't be able to use the tools - particularly the Content Pipeline, but also the Xbox 360/WP7 deployment tools. I suggest you run Windows in a virtual machine or dual-boot.

Comment: Okay, that's probably what I would end up doing anyway. Thanks for the answers!