# MonoGame vs. SDL

Tags: c#, c++, sdl, monogame

Whats the main difference between using the MonoGame with C# and SDL with C++?

Which of them is easier to use? Which is recommended for multi-platform support?

Its important for us to have structure and all-pervading OOP. It should be performant but not at the cost of productivity (e.g. not reinventing the wheel or managing memory). We are a small team so we need a structured, simple and clear framework, which allows us to concentrate on the actual work.

Answer (score 3):

C++ with SDL is native and can run on almost any platform (cross-platform), more specifically those with limited system specifications.

C# with MonoGame is great for proto-typing a concept, but you could run into unavoidable bottle necks for large games.  Additionally, SDL is just a graphics layer, where MonoGame is a complete API for interactive media.  MonoGame *could* be cross-platform too, but I am unsure of its complete audience.

[Is MonoGame really cross-platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397480/is-monogame-really-cross-platform)

You will do a little work from scratch when using C++ with SDL, but there are many libraries out there for C++ game development that will make it a breeze.  If productivity is an issue, then you could have problems using C++, unless you use an existing framework for your game, which typically handles memory management.  But that is the risk you take with C++; write more efficient code in a longer time frame.

Irrlicht is a great library for rendering.  Simple and clean.
http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Which of them do you think needs less time to code a simple 2D game?

Comment: For 2D rendering and game development, I would look at Simple Fast Media Library.  http://www.sfml-dev.org/

Don't underestimate your task.  Writing a game is more than just the development of code.  You need a strict design and a little bit of time.  Game development can be a headache at first, but over time things will get easier.  If you are worried about time, then writing a game will give you a nervous break down.

Comment: "SDL is just a graphics layer", this statement is just wrong. Please visit the website to learn more about SDL.

Comment: SDL is not graphics only. It's even in the name. "Simple DirectMedia Layer"